# Convert time hh:mm:ss into GMT time format in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

Input:-

time: 21:00:00

Output Should Be:-

time: Wed Dec 20 2017 21:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

OR

time: 2017-12-20 21:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is : **21:00:00**

Split your input by **':'** using JS code below:

```
let timeArr = "21:00:00".split(':');
```

then, use new date function to add date to the time i.e,

```
let newDateTime = new Date().setHours(timeArr[0], timeArr[1],0,0);
```

then you can convert your time to,

```
let finalDate = new Date(newDateTime);
```

**and you will get the finalDate = Wed Dec 20 2017 21:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)**

Comment: Thank You, it's really useful for me.